# Swap using two threads

Tags: java, multithreading

In process of learning MUltithreading I taught to solve below mentioned problem

You have a String array of alphabets in asc order, the last spot being empty.

Have 2 threads handle the swapping of alphabets, one thread taking letter from the front (i.e., 'a') and swapping with the empty spot, while the second thread takes letter from last (i.e., 'z') and moving it to the empty spot on front

> **Input**:- ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_
>   **Ouput**:-ZYXWVUTSRQPON_MLKJIHGFEDCBA

Below is the program I have dome for this problem. But I need to know is there better way to achieve same.

//AlphaSwap

```
public class AlphaSwap {

    String input[] = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s",
            "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "_" };
    int start = 0;
    int end = 26;
    boolean flag;

    private String[] swap(String input[], int start, int end) {
        String temp = input[start];
        input[start] = input[end];
        input[end] = temp;

        return input;
    }

    public synchronized void swapLast(String input[]) {
        if( flag){
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        String[] swap = swap(input, start, end);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        for (String string : swap) {
            System.out.print(string);
        }
        System.out.println();
        this.end--;
        flag = true;
        notify();
    }

    public synchronized void swapFirst(String input[]) {
        if(!flag){
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        String[] swap = swap(input, start, end);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        for (String string : swap) {
            System.out.print(string);
        }
        System.out.println();
        this.start++;
        flag = false;
        notify();
    }


}
```

//Runner main class

```
public class RunnerMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AlphaSwap alphaSwap = new AlphaSwap();

        new SwapLast(alphaSwap);
        new SwapFirst(alphaSwap);
    }
}
```

//SwapFirst

```
public class SwapFirst implements Runnable{

    private AlphaSwap swap;

    public SwapFirst(AlphaSwap swap) {
        this.swap = swap;
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
                swap.swapFirst(swap.input);
        }
    }
}
```

//swapLast

```
public class SwapLast implements Runnable {
    private AlphaSwap swap;

    public SwapLast(AlphaSwap swap) {
        this.swap = swap;
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
                swap.swapLast(swap.input);
        }
    }

}
```

Any improvement in above code can be done?

Comment: Improvement? : do it in one thread. This approach uses two threads, yet only one can progress at a time.

Comment: explain better ? there are many ways - what is your goal ?

Comment: @bowmore I am practicing this to learn multhithreading, my intention is to know what is best way to achieve this using multhithreading

Comment: Ok, but it's at least as important to learn when to use multiple threads, and when not to.

Comment: @bowmore I totally agree with you, It is just for practice purpose

Answer (score 2):

Actually, after thinking about it there is a swap algorithm that works in parallel, but it isn't yours

```
void swapThread(Object array[], int offset, int step) {
    int index = offset;
    while(index < array.size()/2) {
        Object temp = array[index];
        array[index] = array[array.size()-1-index]; 
        array[array.size()-1-index] = temp;
        index += step;
    }
}
```

You call that function with step as the number of threads you're running, and each thread with a different offset from 0 to the number of threads-1.

For example for 4 threads, you'd have the 4 threads calling

```
swapThread(array, 0, 4);
swapThread(array, 1, 4);
swapThread(array, 2, 4);
swapThread(array, 3, 4);
```

THe big reason this algorithm is better is that it can run as many threads as you want, and that none of the threads operate on the same indices ever, so there's no possibility of a race condition.